# Qt & OpenGL : texture transparency

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, textures, transparency

I have two textures rendered in the same way. The green texture has the right transparency in the right places, but when I move the pink texture in front, it shows the background color where it should be transparent.

[image]

This is the snippet code of the **paintGL** method that renders the textures.

```
void OpenGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    // ...

    for (int i = 0; i < lights.size(); i++)
    {
        glUseProgram(lights[i].program);

        setUniform3fv(program, "lightPosition", 1, &lights[i].position[0]);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, lights[i].texture);

        lights[i].svg.setColor(toColor(lights[i].diffuse));
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, lights[i].svg.width(), lights[i].svg.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, lights[i].svg.toImage().constBits());
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glBindVertexArray(lights[i].vertexArray);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, lights[i].indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
    }

    update();
}
```

The **toImage** method of the **svg** class generates a new QImage object from the svg file, so the new texture value should be updated with each frame.

Where am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Aside: there's no need to call `glTexImage2D` and `glGenerateMipmap` each time you render. Only upload textures and generate mipmaps when they actually change.

Answer (score 2):

This probably happens because you have depth testing enabled. Even though parts of the texture are (partly or fully) transparent, OpenGL still writes to the depth buffer, so the pink light's quad appears to obscure the green light. It works the other way round, because the pink light is drawn first, so the green light hasn't been written to the depth buffer at that point.

The usual solution to this is to render transparent textures in back to front order.

You could also just write your fragment shader to `discard` fragments if they are transparent. But this results in artifacts if you have semi-transparent fragments, which you have, because of texture filtering and mipmaps.

Comment: Perhaps, instead of `discard` transparent fragments better change their depth by using `gl_FragDepth`

Comment: @Ripi2 No, in the early days of OpenGL the solution for this was the alpha test. Nowadays the equivalent solution is to discard fragments in the fragment shader by the [`discard`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader) keyword, dependent on the alpha value of the fragment - in other words to code an alpha test in the fragment shader.

Comment: @thomas Thanks a lot! If I sort the textures according to their depth value (position.z) before drawing them, the problem is solved! ;) But there is still a case in which this strategy does not help: when two textures are exactly at the same depth, that is when the position.z values of the two textures are equal. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Well, what would you _want_ to happen in that case...?